# PHP variable in CSS Class

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to select a CSS class based on the php variable. This is for an estate agentcy. Here is my code but it does not work and I am not sure why:

```
<td width="130" height="30" align="center" class="propertyStatus">
    <?php
        $pStatus = "notAvailable";
            if($property->status = 'Available') {$pStatus = "available";}
    ?>
    <span class="<?php echo $pStatus ?>"><?php echo $property->status ?></span>
</td>
```

It always shows as "Avaible" rather than Sold when properties are sold.

Help is apreciated.

Comment: Maybe instead of $property->status = using the double == the single one normally is used to SET a var, not to check the value.

Comment: Marty, this is to simply status that are returned because there are 5-6 different ones. So I want one style for Avaialble and another for whatever else. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be `if($property->status == 'Available')`

because `$property->status = 'Available'` <= this assigns the values and doesn't compare it!!

what your are doing currently is **assigning the value** whereas you have to **compare the 2 strings**!!

so it should be

```
 <?php
        $pStatus = "notAvailable";
            if($property->status == "Available") /*double equal to sign here*/
            {
               $pStatus = "available";
            }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `==` instead of `=`  and it should be,

```
if($property->status == 'Available') {$pStatus = "available";}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to do something like this:

```
<span class="<?php echo strtolower($property->status); ?>">
```

But yes, the problem is on the = instead of ==